# Laravel-7 pdf validation rule not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-validation

I am trying to validate laravel 7 form validation. But "**mimes:pdf**" is not even passing the pdf files.

Here is my complete code.

Even if I choose pdf files and submit the form the validation says

> The goods serv tax no photo must be a file of type: pdf

The "nullable" validation rule combined with it is working if no files choosen

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        //validation rules
         'party_type_id' => 'required',
         'goods_serv_tax_no' => 'nullable|size:15|alpha_num',
         'perm_acc_no' => 'nullable|size:10|alpha_num',
         'goods_serv_tax_no_photo' => 'nullable|mimes:pdf',
         'perm_acc_no_photo' => 'nullable|file|mimes:pdf|max:300',
         'current_name' => 'required|max:50',
         'gender' => 'nullable|unique:App\PersonGenderType,id',
         'marital_status' =>'unique:App\PersonMaritalStatusType,id',
         'birth_date' =>'nullable|date' ,
         'permanent_retirement_acc_no' => 'nullable|digits:10',
         'universal_acc_no' => 'nullable|digits:12',
         'aadhaar_no' => 'nullable|digits:12',
         'photo' => 'nullable|mimes:jpeg|max:300',
         'father_name' => 'max:50',
         'mother_name' => 'max:50',
         'address1' => 'required|max:50',
         'address2' => 'max:100',
         'address3' => 'max:100',
         'city' => 'max:20',
         'land_mark' => 'max:30',
         'state' => 'required|exists:states,id',
         'district' => ' required|exists:districts,id',
         'pincode' => 'nullable|digits:6',
         'email' => 'max:100',
         'mobile' => 'nullable|digits:10',
         'party_roles' => 'digits:10'
         
    ];     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using this:

`'perm_acc_no_photo.*' => 'nullable|file|mimes:pdf|max:300',`

It works for me!

ref here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/nullable-not-working-for-me-with-the-validator